# How do you create primary amines from alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, alcohols, amines

By a primary amine I mean a compound where the hydroxyl group of the corresponding alcohol is replaced with an amine group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For  **aliphatic compounds** you can use [alkylation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amine#Synthesis)

$$\ce{R-OH + NH3 -> R-NH2 + H2O}$$

---

For **aromatic compounds** like phenol

$$
\begin{matrix}
\ce{C6H6O &\quad +& Zn& \ ->& C_6 H_6\\
Phenol&  & (dust\ form)& \ & Benzene&}
\end{matrix}
$$

Zinc dust reduces the OH group in phenol

---

$$\begin{matrix}
\ce{C6H6& + &HNO3& ->[H2SO4]& C6H5NO2 + &H_2 O&\\
Benzene& & (high\  concentration)&& Nitrobenzene&  water&
}
\end{matrix}$$
[Nitration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatic_nitration)

---

$$\begin{matrix}
\ce{C6H5NO2& +& Sn& +& \qquad HCl_{(aq)} ->& C6H5NH2&\\
Nitrobenzene& & Tin& &Hydrochloric & Aniline&\\
&&&&acid}
\end{matrix}$$ 
$ $ 
 Tin and hydrochloric acid act as reducing agents

Comment: I think you are oversimplifying and skipping a few steps and issues by just saying "alkylation". For a good answer I'd like to see the *details* and complications. Sure it is possible, but it isn't *easy* and that's what usually matters in chemistry.

Comment: (-1) That "alkylation" doesn't work.

Answer (score 27):

In the conversion of primary alcohols to primary amines

$$\ce{R-CH2OH -> R-CH2NH2}$$

direct alkylation of ammonia normally is the last thing you want to do in the lab.

Under conditions where $\ce{OH}$ is a good leaving group, i.e. in acidic medium, the nucleophilicity of ammonia is reduced due to protonation. Moreover, there's little chance to prevent further alkylation of the initial product.

More promising strategies are:

- *Gabriel* synthesis: Hydroxy-halogen-exchange, followed by reaction of the primary halide with phthalimide and subsequent hydrazinolysis
- *Mitsunobu* reaction ($\ce{Ph3P, DEAD}$) of the primary alcohol using hydrazoic acid $\ce{HN3}$ as a nucleophile, followed by reduction of the alkyl azide
- An (almost-one-pot) combination of the *Appel* and the *Staudinger* reaction

  1. Heat the primary alcohol ($\ce{R-CH2OH}$) with $\ce{Ph3P}$  and bromotrichloromethane $\ce{CBrCl3}$ in benzene, then cool down to RT (room temperature) to yield $\ce{R-CH2Hal}$
  2. Add $\ce{NaN3}$,tetrabutylammonium bromide and *N*,*N*-dimethylformamide and reflux again to obtain the azide $\ce{R-CH2N3}$, then cool down to RT, pour on water, extract with benzene and dry the organic layer
  3. Add triethylphosphite $\ce{(EtO)3P}$ to the organic layer, stir at RT to yield the iminophosphorane $\ce{R-CH2N=P(OEt)3}$
  4. Hydrolyze the iminophosphorane by refluxing with hydrochloric acid, then neutralize to release the amine

Comment: Mitsunobu was my first though. Appel is nice, too. Interestingly, I'd never heard of the *Gabriel Synthesis*; nice.

Comment: In place of using hydrazoic acid, DPPA might be a slightly less dangerous alternative (albeit more expensive and less atom economic).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the method provided by [t3st](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/139/t3st) you could also try the following for 
$$\begin{matrix}
\ce{Ph-OH& +& Zn& ->& C6H6 \\
Phenol& & Zinc& & Benzene&}
\end{matrix}$$
(Just like the first step of t3st 's answer.

---

Then you could do [Electrophilic halogenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophilic_halogenation) of benzene using $\small\ce{AlCl3\ or\ FeBr3}$ as catalyst.
$$\begin{matrix}
\ce{C6H6& ->[\ce{Cl2/AlCl3}]& Ph-Cl\\
Benzene& & Aryl\ halide&}
\end{matrix}$$

---

Finally you could react aryl-halide with soda-amide($\small\ce{NaNH2}$) to substitute $\ce{Cl}$ with $\ce{NH2}$<sup><sup>[citation needed]</sup></sup>
$$\begin{matrix}
\ce{Ph-Cl& ->[\ce{NaNH2}]& Ph-NH2&\\
Aryl halide& & Aniline&}
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Low yields all the way with this route

Answer (score 0):

For PhOH to PhNH2 Pd catalysis offers a better route than Zn reduction etc.
Formation of the triflate by reaction with triflic anhydride then reaction under Pd catalysis with a source of N (I've used benzophenone imine or acetamide but there are others) then finally aqueous hydrolysis gets to the aniline in fairly respectable yield.